# ubuntu on a usb for boot up

Tags: boot, usb, downloads

Can anyone help me? I'm trying to download ubuntu on a usb to load onto a new laptop. Here's a screen shot of what I get, and I just don't know enough to figure out what my mistake is.
Never mind, this forum won't let me send a screen shot, and it seems there is SO much out there in piles  & piles of forums, you never can just get any actual HELP :(

Basically it doesn't offer any usb option, just a dvd choice. I just don't get what I need to do.

Comment: You can upload your screenshot to many number of sites out there, then post a link to it in your question.

Comment: If it is a new system, it then is UEFI. You may have to turn secure boot off and/or specifically allow booting from USB. Many systems lock that out unless specifically allowed. What brand/model system? Some (Acer) require you to set a password to open up those extra settings. Never lose that password.

Answer (score 0):

I'll quote google's answer:

> To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is
>   insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space into your PC. The
>   easiest way to put Ubuntu onto your stick is to use the USB installer
>   provided at pendrivelinux.com. You'll need to download and install and
>   follow the instructions.

So go to:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR RESPONDING!
I am downloading from an ubuntu system with an 8G stick (sorry I didn't mention that), but I must be downloading from the wrong source!

Comment: I get a small window box  that pops up titled "IMAGE BURNING SETUP" & says:
 
select a disc image to write

with a small button to click 
....md64.iso 1.0GB

another button shadowed out (so not 'clickable') 
says: no disc available 
and a button that reads properties

Comment: since you are going to work with USB, I don't think you need to perform image burning so just cancel that.